# Fitting JQWidget Splitter on Any Screen Size

Tags: jquery, jqxwidgets

From **[this example](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxsplitter/defaultfunctionality.htm?energyblue)**, is it possible  to adjust its size to fit on any screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this sample: [jQWidgets Splitter Full Screen Demo](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/mobiledemos/jqxsplitter/defaultfunctionality.htm?%28android%29&=fullscreen)